# jcfis Copying files from OS X

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

Is it possible to access a Samba share hosted on OS X using jcifs?

I can't get past login:

When
    `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity", "false");`

I get the error `Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.1.8`

When `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity", "true");`

I get the error `jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password`

Everything works fine when hosted on Windows servers.  Are there any alternatives sharing options for Java (afp://)?

Comment: Are you able to access the OS X share from a Windows client (without Java)?

Comment: Yes - accessing the share from natively from Windows works fine (net use) only have problems when trying to use jcifs